# Eclipse SVN client (Subclipse) doesn't show status icons on files

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse, phpeclipse

I've been using Eclipse PHP since quite a while with Subclipse, but suddenly, the tiny icons which appear before the files in the PHP Explorer and Navigator don't appear any more.

I've already re-installed Eclipse and the Subclipse plugin, to no avail.

I am using Subclipse for SVN and the functionality seems to be working just fine, just the icons don't appear.

It's quite tough to manually remember which files I've edited/updated if I don't see these icons.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? (I am on [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx).)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Search the preference menu Window > Preferences for "Decoration", and make sure general > appearance > label decoration > SVN is checked. Also, check options under Team > SVN > Label Decorations. You may need to disable and re-enable these settings for them to work again.

Comment: disconnect and then team share project worked for me

Answer (score 7):

I had to delete the project (without removing contents from disk), then re-import my project using File > Import > Other > Existing Folder.

Comment: This is the working solution, even if it's a workaround in order to solve a bug of the IDE

Answer (score 3):

I has had the same issue with subversive.
To see that decoration in synchronisation view I had to 
uncheck "File Icons Based On Content Analysis" in 
Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Label Decorations

Comment: I have just upgraded my Eclipse to Oxygen 3. I use SVN and get this bug in Synchronize. Your solution fix my problem. Thank you.